# Eliminate Duplicate Rows based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Each time the row is updated, a new row is inserted along with a variation id. The table looks like:

First table:

```
ID1         variation_id1
111            1
111            1
```

Second table:

```
ID2    ID-LineNO   variation_id2
111      10            1
111      20            1
111      10            2
111      20            2
```

The result should be:

```
ID1    ID2   ID-LineNO   variation_id2    
111    111     10            2               
111    111     20            2
```

I want to pick the ID based on latest variation id along with the respective line number.

```
Select DISTINCT ID2,ID1,ID-LineNO,variationid1
from second table
inner join first table on ID1 = ID2
where variation_id2 in (select max(variation_id2)
                        from second table 
                        where variation_id2 = variation_id2 
                        group by ID2)
```

I tried above code to get the result but still getting duplicate rows.Can you please help me how to eliminate duplicate rows based on variation id.

Comment: Why do you have duplicates in the first table?

Comment: According to our business process, we get duplicate rows if the same transaction is published again and need only latest transaction.

Answer (score 2):

In your sub-query, you need to alias the tables so the sub-query will correlate to the outer query and not to itself:

```
Select DISTINCT ID2,ID1,ID-LineNO,variationid1
from second_table t2
inner join first_table t1 on t1.ID1 = t2.ID2
where variation_id2 in (select max(variation_id2)
                        from second_table t3
                        where t3.variation_id2 = t2.variation_id2 
                        group by ID2)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried as suggested but some of the ID's getting duplicates and some of the ID's are not getting duplicates.

Comment: The sample data in your question would not produce duplicates with this answer.   If you are getting duplicates, edit your question and add the data that is resulting in duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand the question, in the first table there isn't a primary key and in the second you didn't speciified which is, but I think you wrote the wrong "variationid" in the select clause. I'd like to have a clearest example, in this isn't necessary to write the WHERE clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID2,ID1,ID-LineNO,variationid2
FROM second_table INNER JOIN first_table on ID2 = ID1
WHERE variationid2 in (
    SELECT max(variation_id2)
    FROM second_table 
    GROUP BY ID2
)
```

Comment: Hi Heichou, variation-id is the primary key in both tables.

Comment: Hi, but this is duplicated. In this example I know only that you want to print the rows with biggest variant_id2 but having ID1 = ID2

Comment: Not duplicated.ID1 will have many line numbers i.e In this example ID1 has two lines nothing but 10 and 20.so ID1 has two lines with same variation ID(primary key).I want to print the ID with respective lines and variationid.I tried your code still getting duplicate values

Comment: Maybe you need an alias, you could try to add in the select "variationid2 as vid2" and in the internal select add "WHERE vid2=variation_id2"

Answer (score 1):

If you join again with Max(variation_Id2) you will be able to get required results.

```
  Select DISTINCT [second table].ID2,ID1,[ID-LineNO],variation_id2
    from [second table]
    inner join [first table] on ID1 = [second table].ID2
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Id2, MAX(variation_Id2) AS MaxiD FROM [second table] GROUP BY Id2) S ON S.Id2 = [second table].Id2
    WHERE variation_id2 = S.MaxiD
```

Comment: Hi Nagashree, I tried as per your suggestion but while executing I am getting an error as "The correlation name 'second table' has the same exposed name as table 'second table'.please guide me

Comment: I have edited to match with the query in the question.